# Index warning python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use pandas and build a new feature using one of the current features like this one:

```
df['col_2'] = df.loc[:, 'col_1'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('/')[0]))
```

However, I get this warning. How can I avoid it?

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Please note I am not interested to ignore this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to replicate the error you were experiencing.  Can you confirm what version of Pandas you have installed?

However, I was able to achieve the results I believe you were looking for with the following adjusted code:

```
df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('/')[0]))
```

If you are applying this transformation to every row, df.loc[:, 'col_1'] and df['col_1'] should return the same.

My full test code is below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'col_1':[
        '0/Usidore', 
        '1/Wizard of the 12th Realm of Ephysiyies', 
        '2/Master of Light and Shadow',
        '3/Manipulator of Magical Delights',
        '4/Devourer of Chaos',
        '5/Champion of the Great Halls of Terr\'akkas',
        '6/elves/Fi’ang Yalok',
        '7/dwarfs/Zoenen Hoogstandjes',
        '8/northeast/Gaismunēnas Meistar'
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('/')[0]))

df
```

And returns

```
    col_1                                         col_2
0   0/Usidore                                     0
1   1/Wizard of the 12th Realm of Ephysiyies      1
2   2/Master of Light and Shadow                  2
3   3/Manipulator of Magical Delights             3
4   4/Devourer of Chaos                           4
5   5/Champion of the Great Halls of Terr'akkas   5
6   6/elves/Fi’ang Yalok                          6
7   7/dwarfs/Zoenen Hoogstandjes                  7
8   8/northeast/Gaismunēnas Meistar               8
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `df` was created as a view, but it's hard to tell without seeing the code used to create `df`. Please see this section of the pandas docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy